# Known coefficient in multiple linear model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

Lets say my model is :

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x-2+\beta_3x_3$

Now lets say I know for sure that $\beta_2 = 4$.

My teacher said I should create $y’ = y-4 X_2$ and ordinary least squares (ols) that.

And after all estimates are done add up again the same value to get to the true value of y.

I said why not keep it as 4 and use same $y$ and use ols with 4 as input?

Comment: You're confusing the value of $\beta_2$ with the value of $x$. Even your third expression is written wrong. If you know $\beta_2= 4$ then you should express y-prime as $y^\prime = y - 4x$. Another way to do this is set offset = $4x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "use ols with 4 as input"?

Answer (score 1):

These are identical. Either way, you are solving the same optimization problem to optimize three parameters: $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_3$. However, this is a bit of a specialized problem, and software is not necessarily readily available to solve this problem the way such software is available for OLS. Thus, the options are either to write your own specialized optimization code, find software that does it, or do this little subtraction workaround and use standard OLS software.

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you suggest (fix β2 to 4 in the model and estimate the remaining coefficients) in programs for structural equation modeling such as lavaan in R (other programs are Mplus and AMOS). The program will then estimate the remaining coefficients as free parameters using maximum likelihood estimation. The program will also give you a chi-square test that allows you to test the null hypothesis that β2 = 4 in the population.

Comment: It seems as if lavaan is a bit overengineered for this task. The obvious function in R for OLS is `lm`. It has an `offset` argument for cases like this.